# JS 4 digit array counter

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to make a 4 digit counter (e.g. 0000, 0001, ... 0152, 0153, ...) in JS and I have created the following logic, however, I have a bug when the numbers reach something like 0099. Is there a better way of doing this?

```
    c = [0,0,0,0]
    c = c.reverse();

    c[0]++;

    for (let i = 0; i < c.length-1; i++) {
        if (c[i] >= 9) {
            if(i > 0 && c[i-1] != 9){
            } else {
                c[i] = 0;
                if (c[i+1] == 9) {
                    c[i+1] = 0;
                    c[i+2]++;
                } else {
                    c[i+1]++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    c = c.reverse().join("");
```

Comment: Do you have any specific requirements for *how* you do this that led you to using an array? The simple, straightforward way would be a number and `theNumber.toString().padStart(4, "0")` (or `toLocaleString` with `minimumIntegerDigits`)...

Comment: Please add the loop outside this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just count up an int and then convert it to 4-digits with

```
myInt.toLocaleString("en", {minimumIntegerDigits: 4, useGrouping: false})
```